# Almacenar columnas de un txt en un array

Tags: c

Estoy trabajando con un archivo de texto que tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
AGE SEX BMI      BP  S1  S2     S3  S4   S5     S6   Y
59  2   32.1    101 157 93.2    38  4   4.8598  87  151
```

El archivo tiene 442 líneas y cada una de ellas responde a un caso concreto.
Mi problema es que necesito almacenar las columnas AGE, SEX y BMI de los 442 casos en diferentes array, para posteriormente hacer operaciones con esos datos(media del BMI según rangos de edad y sexo) y mostrarlos finalmente a modo de resumen(tabla) y no se por donde tirar para poder recorrer el archivo completo y almacenar específicamente cada una de las tres columnas en un array.

Inicialmente he leído el archivo completo, he leído línea por línea el archivo y he usado la función strtok para dividir la cadena por tabulaciones. La salida ahora es la siguiente:

```
AGE
SEX
BMI
BP
S1
S2
S3
S4
S5
S6
Y

59
2
32.1
101
157
93.2
38
4
4.8598
87
151
```

Y después los 441 casos restantes.

Ahora lo que quiero es almacenar cada valor de cada caso en un vector, es decir, tener los 8 valores diferentes de todos los casos almacenados en 8 vectores diferentes y no se por donde tirar.

Mi código actual es el siguiente:

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #define LONGITUD_MAXIMA_CADENA 1000 // Cuántos bytes leer en cada iteración
    #define NOMBRE_ARCHIVO "diabetes.txt"
    
    int main(void){
    
       //Declaramos las variables del archivo
      int AGE[442];
      int SEX[442];
      int BMI[442];
      int BP[442];
      int S1[442];
      int S2[442];
      int S3[442];
      int S4[442];
      int S5[442];
      int S6[442];
      int Y[442];
    
      const char s[2] = "\t";
      char *token;
    
    
        FILE *archivo = fopen(NOMBRE_ARCHIVO, "r"); // Modo lectura
        char bufer[LONGITUD_MAXIMA_CADENA];         // Aquí vamos a ir almacenando cada línea
        while (fgets(bufer, LONGITUD_MAXIMA_CADENA, archivo))
        {
            token = strtok(bufer, s);
            // La imprimimos, pero realmente podríamos hacer cualquier otra cosa
            while( token != NULL ) {
             printf( " %s\n", token );
        
             token = strtok(NULL, s);
       }
    
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Otra cosa que no consigo hacer es obviar la primera línea del fichero, pues contiene la cadena de identificadores de los valores y evidentemente no la necesito para hacer cálculos con ella

---

EDITO:

He modificado mi código totalmente, he creado un struct en vez de las 11 variables y creo que he comprendido el uso de atoi junto con strtok.

Bien, creo que los datos han quedado almacenados en el struct. Ahora de alguno de ellos como por ejemplo el BMI necesito hacer la media segun diferentes tramos de edad y sexo. Estoy probando a hacer primero la media de la edad y al imprimir por pantalla los resultados me salen valores extraños y me imprime todo el archivo de texto cuando solo quería el valor de la media de la edad de todos los casos. No se que estoy haciendo mal.

Adjunto mi código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int ordenBMI(FILE *file)
{
    struct datos 
  {
  int AGE;
  int SEX;
  int BMI;
  int BP;
  int S1;
  int S2;
  int S3;
  int S4;
  int S5;
  int S6;
  int Y;
  };
  struct datos diabetes;
  char linea[1024];
  //char basura[1024];
  int i;
  int sumatorio = 0;
    //fscanf(file, "%s", basura);
    for(i = 0; i < 441; i++)
    {

        fgets(linea, 1024, file);
        /* Imprime la linea actual.*/ puts(linea);
        diabetes.AGE = atoi(strtok(linea, "\t"));
        diabetes.SEX = atoi(strtok(NULL, "\t"));
        diabetes.BMI = atoi(strtok(NULL, "\t"));
        diabetes.BP = atoi(strtok(NULL, "\t"));
        diabetes.S1 = atoi(strtok(NULL, "\t"));
        diabetes.S2 = atoi(strtok(NULL, "\t"));
        diabetes.S3 = atoi(strtok(NULL, "\t"));
        diabetes.S4 = atoi(strtok(NULL, "\t"));
        diabetes.S5 = atoi(strtok(NULL, "\t"));
        diabetes.S6 = atoi(strtok(NULL, "\t"));
        diabetes.Y = atoi(strtok(NULL, "\t"));

         for (int x = 0; x < 441; x++){
           sumatorio += diabetes.AGE;
         }
         float media = (float) sumatorio / (float) 441;
         printf("Media: %f", media);

    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    
    FILE * file;
        file = fopen("diabetes2.txt", "r");

    ordenBMI(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Y mi salida:

```
59  2   32.1    101 157 93.2    38  4   4.8598  87  151

Media: 58.86651648  1   21.6    87  183 103.2   70  3   3.8918  69  75
```

No se que estoy haciendo mal

La salida final que espero es:

```
Sexo/Tramos edad                   Hombres            Mujeres
 
Entre 24 y 35                      Media BMI          Media BMI
Entre 36 y 50                      Media BMI          Media BMI
Entre 51 y 70                      Media BMI          Media BMI
Mas de 71                          Media BMI          Media BMI
```

Gracias a todos

---

EDITO 24/05:

Buenas a todos, finalmente ya tengo mi código funcionando y con el resultado esperado.
En general estoy satisfecho salvo por un par de detalles que se me escapan:
El primero de ellos es que necesito redirigir la salida hacia un archivo txt vacio y no se me ocurre como hacerlo. Mi salida es la siguiente:

```c
        printf("----------------------------------------\n");
        printf("\t\t\tmedia BMI\n");
        printf("Resultado \tHombres \tMujeres\n");
        printf("Entre 0 y 24 \t%.2f \t\t%.2f\n", medh24, medm24);
        printf("Entre 25 y 44 \t%.2f \t\t%.2f\n", medh25_44, medm25_44);
        printf("Entre 45 y 64 \t%.2f \t\t%.2f\n", medh45_64, medm45_64);
        printf("65 o mas \t%.2f \t\t%.2f\n", medh65, medm65);
        printf("----------------------------------------\n");
```

La segunda es que sigo sin saber como obviar la primera linea del fichero, donde aparacen las etiquetas de los identificadores. Mi código funciona porque he usado un archivo modificado sin las cabeceras para ir avanzando con el problema, pero no he sabido como hacerlo.

Gracias a todos por la ayuda

Comment: Pues busca ejemplos de cómo leer un fichero línea a línea. Una vez que tengas cada línea, busca ejemplos de cómo separar campos de una línea buscando tokens (separadores que en tu caso serán caracteres espacio), y ejemplos de cómo crear arrays. No es tan complicado. Prueba a intentarlo y vuelve con lo que no te funcione.

Comment: Ahora necesita definir un array de structs para guardar en cada posición del array cada elemento: `struct datos diabetes[441];` En el `for` vas posicionando cada uno `diabetes[i].AGE` (y las demás variables del sctruct). Y una vez tienes tu array de scructs posicionado, entonces te dedicas a recorrerlo buscando los que son de tal edad, y vas sumando sus lo que sea. Ojo que has definido todo int y tienes datos que no son enteros en tu fichero...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para no leer la primera línea antes del while pon un `fscanf`. Los datos que saque te dan igual y los puedes poner en una variable que no vas a usar. Su única funcion es avanzar una línea en el archivo.

Te recomiendo que para este caso uses un `struct` que es más facil que declarar 11 variables y para poner los datos que lees con el fgets (char) en una variable `int` tienes que usar `atoi` que viene en la librería `<string.h>`

Comment: Muchas gracias por indicarme el uso de atoi, no conocía dicha función. Ahora tengo problemas con la salida de datos

Comment: Lo siento esque estoy estudiando c por mi cuenta y me faltan algunos elementos de base .. Se me ocurre como hacer tu programa pero no entineod como lo has intentado hacer basicamente porque no entiendo el += Aparte me puedes aclarar si tiene que hacer diferentes medias según la edad de la gente

Comment: Toda ayuda es bienvenida, yo también soy muy novato en C. La media está realizada siguiendo un ejemplo que encontré ,así que seguramente esté mal. Por otra parte si que se tienen que hacer medias según diferentes tramos de edad y sexo. Por ejemplo, los que tienen entre 24 y 35 años y son mujeres tienen una media, los que tienen entre 24 y 35 tienen otra media, y asi sucesivamente, es decir, hay 4 tramos para cada sexo. En este caso además AGE con valor 1 corresponde a un hombre y con valor dos a una mujer

Comment: @Álvaro pues si quieres esta tarde te mando el programa como lo haría yo para que lo veas.

Comment: Muy agradecido Julián, hasta lo más mínimo ayuda. Yo lo estoy intentando a mi manera y siguiendo con el código que estaba haciendo, pero otro punto de vista me me vendría muy bien. Gracias nuevamente por tu ayuda

Comment: @Álvaro Estoy haciendo un problema y me ha surgido una complicación XD me puedes pasar tu archivo porfa (No se si se puede hacer por aqui pero me puedes pasar un enlace a google drive)

Comment: Te dejo el archivo de datos que yo utilizo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zf-phes-UbwMWc2fxr2_6BSnSu0vrQhE/view?usp=sharing